# get the data from the server in Angular5

Tags: angular5

How to get the data from Server using Angular5.
i want to about Get call in Angular5

i tried this:

```
getField (): Observable<b_fld[]> {
    return this.http.get<fld[]>(this.fieldUrl)
      .pipe(
        tap(fields => console.log(`fetched fields`))
      );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it is.
This is my `service.ts` set up.

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

Import the `HttpClient` and `HttpHeaders` and then set them up like below

```
accessToken;
apiUrl = environment.apiUrl; // Url Reads http://my-api.com 

// Only Needed if you have headers    
headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', this.accessToken);

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
) { }

getMyData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(
        this.apiUrl + '/my-data', // Url Reads http://my-api.com/my-data
        {headers: this.headers} // Include Headers If needed
    );
}
```

Then inside my `compoinent.ts` file look like this.

`import { MyService } from '../../services/my.service';`

```
...
data;
...

constructor(
    ...
    private myService: MyService
    ...
) { }

async ngOnInit() {
    try {
        await this.getData();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
    this.loaded = true;
}

async getData() {
    this.data = await this.getMyData();
}

// Get the Data
getMyData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.myService.getMyData()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                resolve(data);
            }, err => {
                reject(err);
            }
        );
    });
}
```